# php delete in witdh explode update

Tags: php

when I delete the category from the reference category, it completely erases the reference post in the reference table.

I want is if the category is deleted, the "reference_categories" in the reference table; If the number is 1, delete it, if not, update it and delete the id there.

**DELETE**

```
$table = get('table');
$column = get('column');
$id = get('id');

$query = $db->delete($table)
->where($column, $id)
->done();

if ($table == 'reference_categories') {

if ($query) {

$reference = $db->from('reference')
->where('reference_categories', $id)
->first();

$db->delete('reference')
->where('reference_categories', $id)
->done();

}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before anything, you should read up on [database normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) and fix your database architecture instead of storing multiple values/references comma separated in one single column, like you're doing with `reference_categories`. What you currently have is an anti-pattern in relational databases which makes things like this much harder.

Comment: everyone has their own way of eating. I want it to be this way.

Comment: can't a query be interfered in this way

Comment: Why this database design is bad: when searching for all records with a specific category id, the database can't use indexes which affects performance _a lot_. If you want to add, remove an id, you need to fetch the column, modify the string using PHP and update the column again. That's _a lot_ of overhead. You won't be able to join tables based on the category, or at least not easily. This affects performance _a lot_. Your application will also be more complex (since you need to do a lot in PHP that the database otherwise could have handled). Why do you knowingly want to build it wrong?

Comment: so what would you suggest me to do?